# noindex, follow?

Tags: seo, noindex

this is just a simple SEO question.
I have a wordpress SEO plug-in that has this option:

Meta robots: [checkbox] noindex, follow

Should I check this option if I want my page to be available on Google?

Comment: I would recommend posting that question to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com to get better answer

Comment: It would be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. The real question is about the directives me thinks.

Comment: An introduction to the robots meta tag is available here: http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/how-to-use-robots-meta-tags.html

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noindex means that the page may not be indexed and thus the page which is affected by this Robots Exclusion Protocol directive, will not appear in major search engines, including Google. The follow directive doesn't have much to do with whether the page appears in a search engine's results.

See this for more info (applies on most search engines):
[Control Crawling/Indexing](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/)